# Newbie question on grails "createCriteria"

Tags: grails, criteria

I am new to Grails criteria builder, can someone please explain what does the following mean?

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
         def results = c {

             like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
             and {
                 between("balance", 500, 1000)
                 eq("branch", "London")
             }
             maxResults(10)
             order("holderLastName", "desc")
         }
```

Does it mean

- `Select * from account where
  holderFirstName like 'fred%' and
  (balance between 500 and 1000 **and**
  branch='london`')
- `Select * from account where
  holderFirstName like 'fred%' and
  (balance between 500 and 1000 **or**
  branch='london`')

If i want to use "or" and "and" together how do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example would execute as:

```
select * from account 
where holderFirstName like 'Fred%' 
and balance between 500 and 1000 
and branch = 'London'
```

All top level conditions are implied to be AND'ed together.  You could create the same Criteria as:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c {
    like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
    between("balance", 500, 1000)
    eq("branch", "London")
    maxResults(10)
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

To get your second query use this Criteria:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c {
    like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
    or {
        between("balance", 500, 1000)
        eq("branch", London")
    }
    maxResults(10)
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

Nest your `and` / `or` closures for more complex Criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Your current criteria means "and" in the two conditions of balance and branch. so

Select * from account where holderFirstName like 'fred%' and (balance between 500 and 1000 **and** branch='london') is correct, just that it will hold maximum 10 results and will be sorted on the basis of "holderLastName" in descending order.

To use **and** and **or** together you also need to specify an **or** block in criteria, so your criteria will look something like

```
Account.createCriteria()
         def results = c {

             like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
             and {
                 between("balance", 500, 1000)
                 eq("branch", "London")
             }
             or{
                 eq("prop1", prop1)
                 eq("prop2",prop2)
             }
             maxResults(10)
             order("holderLastName", "desc")
         }
```

in this criteria there is an **and** between balance and branch conditions. and also an **or** between prop1 and prop2